# How to download a file using GWT client?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

What is the best way to download a pdf file using GWT client ? Should I invoke a normal servlet to do that ? or is there a different preferred approach to handle this problem ?

I am new to GWT, so if some sample code would be of great help.

Thanks
Deep

Answer (score 4):

Try it with GET...

```
Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "FileRepository/doDownload?docId=" + dokument.getId(), "", "");
```

Comment: Thanks. using this method, can I access any file which is not in the WAR root directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Servlet download the file OR you can do that using [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI):

1. Make your GWT RPC method return the file content or the data to generate the file.
2. On the client side, format a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) with the file content received or generate the data content.
3. Use `Window.open` to open a file save dialog passing the formatted [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI).

Take a look at this reference, to understand the [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) usage:

> [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery/7588465#7588465)

Comment: It no longer works, console says:
"Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL..."
Checked on the Edge.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to navigate your browser to that file

on download button add click handler:

```
Button downloadButton = new Button("Download");
downloadButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.open("url_of_file", "download File", "");            
    }
});
```