# Generating a dynamic file and download it in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, rpc

I am developing a GWT application. This application is running in a server. Well, I implement a button which calls a method that generates a local file in server side. However I would like to download/generate this file in client side. How could I do this in GWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current situation is, that not all browsers are able to work with local file system, so there is no universal solution in GWT. Also as far as I know FilesSstem API is not finished.

As alternative you can keep using serverside generated files, or use Flash plugin to generate and store files (you will have to create a Flash app, and create some API to control it from GWT).

Answer (score 3):

In our project we created a file on server on demand. When the file has been successful created we send notification to browser and created a link.

See servlet code:

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {              
    private FileManager fileManager;        
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String encodedFileName = req.getRequestURI().substring(
                req.getContextPath().length() + req.getServletPath().length() + 1);
        String decodedFileName = URLDecoder.decode(encodedFileName, "utf-8");    
        File downloadableFile = fileManager.toFile(decodedFileName);

        ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(downloadableFile);
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(is, os);
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hy, thanks for the answer,it was exactly what i was looking for! One question to the FileManager class though, i can't seem to find documentation for the usage of the FileManager.toFile(...) method. Is this the [com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/FileManager.html) class?

Comment: No, it is our internal implementation. You have to translate decodedFileName to downloadableFile - real path in your file system.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private native void Download(String filename, String text)/*-{
      var pom = document.createElement('a');
      pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
      pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
      document.body.appendChild(pom);
      pom.click();
     document.body.removeChild(pom); }-*/;
```

Use **JSNI** method inside **GWT** code , provide the file name you want to download in addition to **JSON string** as text (String) , this method will download a file with specified content in text variable to **client browser**.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at [Aki Miyazaki’s HTML5 file download code for GWT](https://github.com/akjava/html5gwt/tree/master/src/com/akjava/gwt/html5/client/download).
It works **on the client side** as you requested.

AFAIK, as of now, it only works in Chrome, but this is supposed to change as other browsers implement the [download attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI):

1. Make your GWT RPC method return the file content or the data to generate the file.
2. On the client side, format a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) with the file content received or generate the data content.
3. Use `Window.open` to open a file save dialog passing the formatted [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI).

Take a look at this reference, to understand the [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) usage:

> [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery/7588465#7588465)