# translate html table to csv

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

So.. I am a little confused on this problem myself so I am turning to the one place I know I am certain to find help!

I have a shopping cart where in order to purchase something a user must first fill out a form. At the end I am displaying the information they entered in the form along with the product they are purchasing, how much they are paying and any sort of modifiers the product might have (like size, color, shipping etc etc). I have a third party company that then needs to retrieve that information in a CSV file.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved. I am new at this sort of thing so I apologize if I may have missed this somewhere else on the forum.

Thanks!
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not too hard! A CSV files is just a comma separated values file.

Whatever you are using as a backend (PHP, c#, c) you can write to a file like so:

CustomerID, Name, Item1

1, John, Table

and that would appear in excel as CustomerID Name and Item1 as the header row and 1, John, Table as the first record. Make sure that when you create the file you call it MyFile.CSV so it is associated with Excel by windows!

Look here for how to properly format your CSV file!

http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm

EDIT:

I see now you say HTML table so in the case you have no server code access I direct you here for more info.

[Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)