# Client side table to Excel with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, export-to-excel

I'd like to client side table to Excel `.xls`, no server side. 
Following code includes simple table and Javascript and table to Excel successfully but doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome?

How can I run it in all browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateExcelSheet()
{
 var x=myTable.rows
   var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
   xls.visible = true
   xls.Workbooks.Add
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
   {
    var y = x[i].cells
    for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
   {
   xls.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = y[j].innerText
  }
  }
 }
</script>


<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr> <b><td>Name </td> <td>Age</td></b></tr>
<tr> <td>Shivani </td> <td>25</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Naren </td> <td>28</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Logs</td> <td>57</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: .xls specifically, or would a .csv suffice?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveXObject` is an Internet Explorer only method. You can't do what you're trying to do purely with jquery/javascript (at least, not trivially)

You're either going to have to use a server-side application that can generate the Excel spreadsheets, or generate a CSV of your file, base64-encode it and navigate the browser to the base64'ed data using the data: URI scheme to trigger a 'download' of the contents you've generated.

Comment: Link to someone using the URI scheme mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery/13814984#13814984