# offline web application handle save in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, save, offlineapps

I am building an offline web application, and I want to be able to change the html of the page before the user saves it. since I cannot seem to find a way to trigger the save as function from javascript (except from IE), I need to just do some prep work before letting the browser save the page. I am not trying to force the user to do anything, just trying to update the page so that it saves it's state to the actual html of the page being saved. I can do this with a button, but i have to then ask the user to press Ctrl+S which is not smooth at all.

So I either need to be able to trigger a browser save from JavaScript, or handle the save event myself before allowing the default callback to happen.

Can this be done in a cross-browser supported way? I have found several pages dealing with the issue, but none clear it up as I wished, so sorry if this sounds like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now become possible with blobs. [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) is a cross platform solution. This will allow saving of any binary resource.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Data URI's. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery) is similar, a javascript-generated CSV file that would be prompted for the user to download.

There may be other solutions but I think they would be proprietary so not future-proof.

Comment: The problem with Data URI's is that I cannot name them appropriately, and load time is bad because it has to load the whole web page from a string in base64. If I use an html data URI, then the webpage simply redirects without downloading, but if I leave it as data, depending on browser, it may not even ask the user what name to use, and certainly does not default to the right extension. Maybe this can be gotten around, but I haven't seen a good example yet. Thanks, though