# Save the current webpage in a single html file format

Tags: javascript, web, window, save-as

I am working on a project where at some point I want to add the functionality of saving the current webpage as HTML, also in pdf, I am saving page in pdf format by this javascript function `window.print()` now I want to save it as HTML, but can't find a way to do this, I hope there would be some function to save as HTML. If you know, let me know, it would be a great help.
Note that you can save the current webpage as Html by a keyboard shortcut Ctrl+S, and print the page using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+P.

Comment: Browsers have "Save" functionality built in.  Does your site not work with that?

Comment: I found a solution, I appreciate that you have taken the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector("html").innerHTML` to get all the HTML of an page.

Then you have a variable containing the entire document as a string - we can download it with the following function:

```
function download(filename, text) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
 encodeURIComponent(text));
 element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177661/save-html-locally-with-javascript)

Also take a look at this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444268/way-to-save-html-file-using-javascript)