# File System Access API: how to send a fileHandle with postMessage?

Tags: javascript, serialization, postmessage, file-system-access-api

I'm working with the File System Access API and I have to send a FileSystemDirectoryHandle calling a postMessage(), according to [this article](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) it seems to be possible

> File handles are serializable, which means that you can save a file handle to IndexedDB, or call postMessage() to send them between the same top-level origin.

I made many try but... noway

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928613/file-system-access-api-is-it-possible-to-store-the-filehandle-of-a-saved-or-loa) [@DenverCoder9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6255000/denvercoder9?tab=tags) proposes a working example for the indexedDb but I can't find anything for the postMessage

Thanks,
Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [fixed bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=955192&q=Serialize%20component%3ABlink%3EStorage%3EFileSystem&can=1) transferring file handles via `postMessage()` is implemented and should work, however, only for same-origin contexts. If it doesn’t work, probably your origins are different.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but just a question, the structured cloning algorithm is also used in indexedDb, do you know why it works in that case?