# File loaded from file handle stored in indexedDB does not update when file is changed and page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, filereader, indexeddb, page-refresh

Using the approach presented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938910/3825996

I have created a webpage where you can drop a file anywhere and the content will be shown. After dropping, the handle of the file is stored in the indexedDB and when the page is refreshed, the last dropped file will be opened again and displayed.

I would expect that if I change the file and reload the page, the new content is displayed, but it is not. However, if I drag and drop the changed file, it will correctly display the changed content.

In Chrome, I also did "Empty cache and hard reload" but it still displayed the old file content.

Why does this happen? Does a file handle store the complete file? What can I do so that the changed file is reloaded after refresh?

Here is the code:
(did not work as html snippet)

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script>
        // stolen from https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval

        function promisifyRequest(request) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                request.oncomplete = request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
                request.onabort = request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
            });
        }

        function createStore(dbName, storeName) {
            const request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
            request.onupgradeneeded = () => request.result.createObjectStore(storeName);
            const dbp = promisifyRequest(request);
            return (txMode, callback) => dbp.then((db) => callback(db.transaction(storeName, txMode).objectStore(storeName)));
        }

        let defaultGetStoreFunc;
        function defaultGetStore() {
            if (!defaultGetStoreFunc) {
                defaultGetStoreFunc = createStore('keyval-store', 'keyval');
            }
            return defaultGetStoreFunc;
        }

        function idbLoad(key, customStore = defaultGetStore()) {
            return customStore('readonly', (store) => promisifyRequest(store.get(key)));
        }

        function idbStore(key, value, customStore = defaultGetStore()) {
            return customStore('readwrite', (store) => {
                store.put(value, key);
                return promisifyRequest(store.transaction);
            });
        }

        function makeKey(domElement) {
            return 'lastOpened-' + domElement.tagName + "-" + domElement.id;
        }

        async function handleFile(domElement, file) {
            await idbStore(makeKey(domElement), file);
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                domElement.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent("handlefilecontent", { detail: e.target.result })
                );
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }

        function dropHandler(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
                [...ev.dataTransfer.items].forEach((item, i) => {
                    if (item.kind === "file") {
                        const file = item.getAsFile();
                        handleFile(ev.currentTarget, file);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                [...ev.dataTransfer.files].forEach((file, i) => {
                    handleFile(ev.currentTarget, file);
                });
            }
        }

        function dragOverHandler(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        async function checkLastOpened(domElement) {
            try {
                let file = await idbLoad(makeKey(domElement));
                if (file) {
                    handleFile(domElement, file)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.name, error.message);
            }
        }

        function dragDropInitialize(domElement, callback) {
            domElement.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler)
            domElement.addEventListener("dragover", dragOverHandler)
            domElement.addEventListener("handlefilecontent", (ev) => { callback(ev.detail) })
            checkLastOpened(domElement)
        }

        dragDropInitialize(document.body, (content) => {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = content
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects returned via `DataTransferItem`'s `getAsFile()` or `DataTransfer`'s `files` list are `File` objects, which are not equivalent to a file handle but represent the data of the file itself - a `File` in the web platform API is basically just a `Blob` with a name.

So when you call `idbStore()` passing the file, you're actually storing the *contents* of the file to the database. At the point when the store happens, implementations will slurp in the contents of the file and store it in the database. This is why you're not seeing new data when you reload the page.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Do you know if there is a way to achieve what I want? Maybe store the data in a .js file and reimport that in some way?

Comment: Chromium-based browsers have shipped a new API for local file access. In that case you are given a FileSystemHandle object, which can be used to read the file and stored in IDB. Note that for privacy/security reasons the user will be re-prompted for access when the handle is subsequently pulled out of the database. You can feature-detect this by testing if a DataTransferItem object has a getAsFileSystemHandle() method, which is how you get access to the handle. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/getAsFileSystemHandle