# Write to file in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple site that generates random number.
I want to record how many times a specific number comes up.

Is there anyway I can use javascript to write to a Local .txt File on the server?

or do I have to learn PHP?

Comment: how are you planning to recird the specific number?

Comment: Assuming it needs to work for many users [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) can, either way some language server-side will be needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript save data to file system (with user prompt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212240/javascript-save-data-to-file-system-with-user-prompt)

Comment: "_Local .txt File on the server_" What is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of the number of times a random number comes up for a single client/browser, you can use **localStorage**.  If you want to keep track of the number of times the random number occurs across all executions, you'll need some sort of server-side processing.

Comment: You want to use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` will be gone once the browser is closed.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any server side processing and this data is critical then you can try GoogleAnalytics code to capture and analyaze the randomly generated data.