# Export HTML table to CSV using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html-table, export-to-csv

I am trying to add a feature of csv download option in my website. It should convert the html table present in the website in to csv content and make it downloadable. Ive been searching through internet for a good plugin and found some usefule ones like [http://www.dev-skills.com/export-html-table-to-csv-file/](https://web.archive.org/web/20131008192222/http://www.dev-skills.com/export-html-table-to-csv-file/)  But it uses php script to do the download part. I was wondering if there is a pure javascript library available to do this feature using server side softwares like node.js without the use of php??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export to csv in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-csv-using-javascript/

Answer (score 131):

Should work on every modern browser and without jQuery or any dependency, here my implementation :

```
// Quick and simple export target #table_id into a csv
function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
    // Select rows from table_id
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
    // Construct csv
    var csv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            // Clean innertext to remove multiple spaces and jumpline (break csv)
            var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
            // Escape double-quote with double-double-quote (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)
            data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
            // Push escaped string
            row.push('"' + data + '"');
        }
        csv.push(row.join(separator));
    }
    var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
    // Download it
    var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Then add your download button/link :

```
<a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('my_id_table_to_export');">Download as CSV</a>
```

CSV file is timedated and compatible with default Excel format.

*Update after comments*: Added second parameter "separator", it can be used to configure another character like `;`, it's useful if you have user downloading your csv in different region of the world because they can use another default separator for Excel, for more information see : https://superuser.com/a/606274/908273

Comment: Excellent! After changing one line from csv.push(row.join(';')); to csv.push(row.join(','));, it worked for me.

Comment: I just looked for information on the default separator for Excel and it depends on the region, so indeed it is possible that for some people it is necessary to change the separator in the code. See : https://superuser.com/a/606274/908273

Comment: Good find @Calumah! Thanks.

Comment: so nice.  i guess the semi-colon delimiter must just be to verify those that use this aren't outright slugs. lol.  anyway, thank you.

Comment: I had to change `var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');` to `var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#' + table_id + ' tr');` to get it working, but all is well now

Comment: This works well, I needed to add a replace for non breaking space characters, like so: var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/\u00a0/g, ''); and then the existing data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' '). I tried to edit the answer, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: This seems to work on Desktop, is there a way to make this work on iOS? Clicking the button on iOS does not start the download.

Comment: For me it appears to be adding a blank row in as the filter row of the grid?.

Comment: anyone had UTF-8 encoding issue. please try this. 
`link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));`

Comment: this is not working with Appla Safari Browser

Comment: Using this in a vue sfc file the cpu usage goes up to 99%

Answer (score 44):

Using just `jQuery`, vanilla `Javascript`, and the `table2CSV` library:

[export-to-html-table-as-csv-file-using-jquery](http://odoepner.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/export-to-html-table-as-csv-file-using-jquery/)

Put this code into a script to be loaded in the `head` section:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);

        var $button = $("<button type='button'>");
        $button.text("Export to spreadsheet");
        $button.insertAfter($table);

        $button.click(function () {
            var csv = $table.table2CSV({
                delivery: 'value'
            });
            window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' 
            + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        });
    });
})
```

Notes:

Requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and [table2CSV](https://github.com/rubo77/table2CSV): Add script references to both libraries before the script above.

The `table` selector is used as an example, and can be adjusted to suit your needs.

It only works in browsers with full `Data URI` support: Firefox, Chrome and Opera, not in IE, which only supports `Data URIs` for embedding binary image data into a page.

For full browser compatibility you would have to use a slightly different approach that requires a server side script to `echo` the CSV.

Comment: Hi... thanks for the answer... but when I try to download the tabletoCsv file from the link that you provided.. it shows the error "page not found"

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! I really apppreciate your help!! I found another interesting option too after a lot of searching  http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Comment: table2csv.com is command line program, the correct link would be on the italo's answer: http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

Comment: I have tried most of the above, but the easiest one is this. http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne Post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Done. Added it as an answer.

Comment: Any way of setting the filename?

Answer (score 15):

There is a very easy free and open source solution at [http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150208082455/http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html)

First download the javascript file and sample files from https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/releases/tag/v1.4

The html page looks like below.

Make sure the the javascript file is in the same folder or change the path of the script in the html file accordingly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Export to excel test</title>
    <script src="excellentexport.js"></script>
    <style>
        table, tr, td {
            border: 1px black solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ExcellentExport.js</h1>

    Check on <a href="http://jordiburgos.com">jordiburgos.com</a> and  <a href="https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport">GitHub</a>.

    <h3>Test page</h3>

    <br/>

    <a download="somedata.xls" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'datatable', 'Sheet Name Here');">Export to Excel</a>
    <br/>

    <a download="somedata.csv" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'datatable');">Export to CSV</a>
    <br/>

    <table id="datatable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column "cool" 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100,111</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>More text</td>
            <td>Text with
                new line</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

It is very easy to use this as I have tried most of the other methods.

Comment: Is it possible to use a button instead of an anchor?

Comment: I have a table that is dynamically generated using javascript.  Apparently, this solution didn't work.  In  return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'datatable' ), what does 'this' referring to?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need PHP script on server side. Do that in the client side only, in browsers that accept [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI):

```
data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,content_encoded_as_url
```

The Data URI will be something like:

```
data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333
```

You can call this URI by:

- using `window.open`
- or setting the `window.location`
- or by the href of an anchor
- by adding the download attribute it will work in chrome, still have to test in IE.

To test, simply copy the URIs above and paste in your browser address bar. Or test the anchor below in a HTML page:

```
<a download="somedata.csv" href="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333">Example</a>
```

To create the content, getting the values from the table, you can use [table2CSV](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602200125/http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php) mentioned by [MelanciaUK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554192/439171) and do:

```
var csv = $table.table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
window.location.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

Answer (score 6):

(1)This is the native javascript solution for this issue. It works on most of modern browsers.

```js
function export2csv() {
  let data = "";
  const tableData = [];
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (const row of rows) {
    const rowData = [];
    for (const [index, column] of row.querySelectorAll("th, td").entries()) {
      // To retain the commas in the "Description" column, we can enclose those fields in quotation marks.
      if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        rowData.push('"' + column.innerText + '"');
      } else {
        rowData.push(column.innerText);
      }
    }
    tableData.push(rowData.join(","));
  }
  data += tableData.join("\n");
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" }));
  a.setAttribute("download", "data.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.btn-group {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>jQuery</td>
      <td>John Resig</td>
      <td>The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>React</td>
      <td>Jordan Walke</td>
      <td>React makes it painless to create interactive UIs.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vue.js</td>
      <td>Yuxi You</td>
      <td>The Progressive JavaScript Framework.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button onclick="export2csv()">csv</button>
</div>
```

(2) If you want a pure javascript library, [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) could help you save the code snippets for triggering file download. Besides, FileSaver.js will not be responsible for constructing content for exporting. You have to construct the content by yourself in the format you want.

Answer (score 6):

**A Modern Solution**

Most of the proposed solutions here will break with nested tables or other elements inside your td elements. I frequently use other elements inside my tables, but only want to export the topmost table. I took some of the code found here from Calumah and added in some modern vanilla ES6 JS.

Using **textContent** is a better solution than innerText as innerText will return any HTML inside your td elements. However, even textContent will return the text from nested elements. An even better solution is to use custom data attributes on your td and pull the values for you CSV from there.

Happy coding!

```
function downloadAsCSV(tableEle, separator = ','){
    let csvRows = []
    //only get direct children of the table in question (thead, tbody)
    Array.from(tableEle.children).forEach(function(node){
        //using scope to only get direct tr of node
        node.querySelectorAll(':scope > tr').forEach(function(tr){
            let csvLine = []
            //again scope to only get direct children
            tr.querySelectorAll(':scope > td').forEach(function(td){
                //clone as to not remove anything from original
                let copytd = td.cloneNode(true)
                let data
                if(copytd.dataset.val) data = copytd.dataset.val.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')
                else {
                    Array.from(copytd.children).forEach(function(remove){
                        //remove nested elements before getting text
                        remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove)   
                    })
                    data = copytd.textContent.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '')
                }
                data = data.replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ').replace(/"/g, '""')
                csvLine.push('"'+data+'"')
            })
            csvRows.push(csvLine.join(separator))
        })
    })
    var a = document.createElement("a")
    a.style = "display: none; visibility: hidden" //safari needs visibility hidden
    a.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvRows.join('\n'))
    a.download = 'testfile.csv'
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click()
    a.remove()
}
```

Edit: cloneNode() updated to cloneNode(true) to get insides

Answer (score 4):

Used the answer above, but altered it for my needs.

I used the following function and imported to my **REACT** file where I needed to download the csv file.

I had a `span` tag within my `th` elements. Added comments to what most functions/methods do.

```
import { tableToCSV, downloadCSV } from './../Helpers/exportToCSV';


export function tableToCSV(){
  let tableHeaders = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('th'))
    .map(item => {
      // title = splits elem tags on '\n',
      // then filter out blank "" that appears in array.
      // ex ["Timestamp", "[Full time]", ""]
      let title = item.innerText.split("\n").filter(str => (str !== 0)).join(" ")
      return title
    }).join(",")

  const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))
  .reduce((arr, currRow) => {
    // if tr tag contains th tag.
    // if null return array.
    if (currRow.querySelector('th')) return arr

    // concats individual cells into csv format row.
    const cells = Array.from(currRow.querySelectorAll('td'))
      .map(item => item.innerText)
      .join(',')
    return arr.concat([cells])
  }, [])

return tableHeaders + '\n' + rows.join('\n')
}

export function downloadCSV(csv){
  const csvFile = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' })
  const downloadLink =  document.createElement('a')
  // sets the name for the download file
  downloadLink.download = `CSV-${currentDateUSWritten()}.csv`
  // sets the url to the window URL created from csv file above
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile)
  // creates link, but does not display it.
  downloadLink.style.display = 'none'
  // add link to body so click function below works
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink)

  downloadLink.click()
}
```

When user click export to csv it trigger the following function in react.

```
  handleExport = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const csv = tableToCSV()
    return downloadCSV(csv)
  }
```

Example html table elems.

```
  <table id="datatable">
        <tbody>
          <tr id="tableHeader" className="t-header">
            <th>Timestamp
              <span className="block">full time</span></th>
            <th>current rate
              <span className="block">alt view</span>
            </th>
            <th>Battery Voltage
              <span className="block">current voltage
              </span>
            </th>
            <th>Temperature 1
              <span className="block">[C]</span>
            </th>
            <th>Temperature 2
              <span className="block">[C]</span>
            </th>
            <th>Time & Date </th>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderData()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this out, could you add the function `currentDateUSWritten()` that you're calling inside of `downloadCSV()`?

Answer (score 2):

I found there is a library for this. See example here:

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons.html

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

In HTML, include following scripts:

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js   
dataTables.editor.min.js   
dataTables.select.min.js
dataTables.buttons.min.js  
jszip.min.js    
pdfmake.min.js
vfs_fonts.js  
buttons.html5.min.js    
buttons.print.min.js
```

Enable buttons by adding scripts like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table-arrays').DataTable({
        dom: '<"top"Blf>rt<"bottom"ip>',
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print'],
        select: true,
    });
} );
</script>
```

For some reason, the excel export results in corrupted file, but can be repaired. Alternatively, disable excel and use csv export.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed the MOST basic functionality to scrape the HTML table data and convert it to a csv file.  None of the values were going to have interfering characters, so I didn't need any escaping or encoding considerations.  I also prefer not to declare single-use variables unless that are valuable in expressing the data that they hold.

I couldn't get the download mechanism to work in the Stacksnippet, but here is a working [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dpvhy5wa/).

Change `my_report` to the `id` of the targeted table.
Change `my_scraped_report.csv` to the desired filename of the downloaded file.

```
function exportToCSV() {
    // The following was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370447/2943403
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#my_report tr'),
          link = document.createElement('a');

    link.download = 'my_scraped_report.csv';
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob(
            [
                Array.from(rows).map(row => {
                    return Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td, th')).map(col => col.innerText).join(',');
                }).join('\n')
            ],
            { type: 'text/plain' }
        )
    );
    link.click();
}
```

The mocked HTML:

```
<button onclick="exportToCSV()" style="margin-bottom: 30px">CSV</button>
<table id="my_report" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="vertical-text" role="row">
            <th></th>
            <th>11/10/2023</th>
            <th>12/10/2023</th>
            <th>13/10/2023</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td class=" text-center">456</td>
            <td class=" text-center">298</td>
            <td class=" text-center">498</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td class=" text-center">123</td>
            <td class=" text-center">321</td>
            <td class=" text-center">466</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td class=" text-center">372</td>
            <td class=" text-center">193</td>
            <td class=" text-center">922</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```