# how to export html(containing label and input tags) data to csv or excel

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table. I want to export this to csv or excel but i am not able to export this. Below is my HTML and javascript. but it is giving me all data with tags.

```
<table id="tableinfo">
    <head>
        <script>
            $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
                window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#tableinfo').html());
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="6" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="7" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="8" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button"  Value="Download" id="btnExport" />
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547198/export-html-table-to-csv][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547198/export-html-table-to-csv

Comment: exoprt to excel or csv is fine for <td>1<td> this. but not able to export input type values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that do this.
Try these plugins : http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php
https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin

Comment: tableExport plugin is throwing me error . showing not a valid Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function