# How to allow colspan and rowspan for export excel in datatable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, excel, datatable

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" align="center">This is header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Class Name</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Enrollment Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1st</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>101</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1st</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>101</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above is my table with header colspan and rowspan, for the table i am adding data table plugin as below

```
$('table').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "paging": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "sScrollXInner": "100%",
            "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, -1], ["50", "100", "500", "All"]],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excelHtml5',
            ]
        });
```

while i am click on the export button it remove the first row and export remaining data how to allow the colspan and rowspan in export excel in datatable plugin. please help me.

Comment: See this -> **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302985/how-to-export-multiple-row-headers-in-jquery-datatables**

Comment: in the link i have small doubt. there have two function one is _fnGetHeaders call from other function but where can i put second function(DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5)

Comment: It is explained in the text: "*Then I changed the code in DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5 in the same file to:*" ...It is BTW the only reasonable way. You will have to tweak the code.

Comment: sorry please explain in jsfiddle

Comment: addRow not a function