# export html-table with jquery

Tags: jquery, excel, csv, export

I would like to export the content of a html table with javascript.

First I would walk through all TD-elements and collect the data to send it in one big POST-query to another PHP-Page, that generates CSV-Excel from it.

Or could I use another framework, that already includes this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7588465/439171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php) is a useful plugin that converts a table to CSV string.

Comment: That page seems not be obtained anymore, I copied the source to github: https://github.com/rubo77/table2CSV

Answer (score 1):

**window.open(MIMEtype, dataContainerItem)** can be used to export the html table data directly from browser without making a server trip. But as per web standards it has some limitations and also we can't handle the output file name. Simple steps to do so are -

1. wrap your html table into a container (DIV).
2. pass the html content of this container(DIV) html to window.open along with MIME type.

ex.

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
```

You may refer- http://codepattern.net/Blog/post/jQuery-export-table-data-into-MS-Excel

and awesome details on its limitations at - [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html/16203218#16203218)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) and [table2CSV](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php):

```
var data = $table.table2CSV({delivery:'value'});

$('<a></a>')
    .attr('id','downloadFile')
    .attr('href','data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data))
    .attr('download','filename.csv')
    .appendTo('body');

$('#downloadFile').ready(function() {
    $('#downloadFile').get(0).click();
});
```

Comment: TableCSV has some bugs and is not developed any more, but there is another fork: https://github.com/ZachWick/TableCSVExport that already implemented some more new features (emptyValue, showHiddenRows, rowFilter)