# Export/Import Web SQL Database

Tags: javascript, html

I have a local SQL Database and I need to export this in any file and import when it's needed.

**EDIT** : 
**I don't wanna use webservice because I wanna to do an app without connection but with export/import database when the device is connected function. As backup...make sense?**

Its possible?

Here is my code

```
function initDatabase() {
try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    } else {
        var shortName = 'DB';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = ' Database';
        var maxSize = 100000; //  bytes
        DB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        createTables();
        selectAll();
    }
} catch(e) {

    if (e == 2) {
        // Version number mismatch.
        console.log("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
        console.log("Unknown error "+e+".");
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I've never exported/imported with javascript. There is a new File API in HTML5 that sounds promising which has decent support: http://caniuse.com/fileapi Otherwise, what I typically do in these scenarios is communicate back and forth with a web service, but that would require server-side programming.

Comment: I wanna to do an app without connection but with export/import database when the device is connected function. As backup...make sense?

Comment: Browser-based javascript is deliberately prevented from accessing the local file system as a rule.  You can use [`data:` URIs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7588465/438971) to achieve a download equivalent in the browser.  If you retrieved the data from the PhoneGap database that you're presumably using, then you could export as CSV as above.

Comment: how can I export as csv? I'm using appmobi