# Convert Json Response to CSV for Ms Excel Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a json response, Now I want to convert it to a .CSV file for MSExcel using JavaScript and show users to download or Open it in a dialog box. Please help me out how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, show us your JSON structure. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`?

Comment: Use Google search a bit more, and then when you have some code come back here.

Comment: I am getting a Json response like {"info":{"totalResultCount":628,"resultIndex":1,"resultCount":20},"resultArray":[{"refId":789,"refType":"Location","refValue":"Ornskoldsvik","enabled":"Y"},{"refId":790,"refType":"Location","refValue":"Drayton","enabled":"Y"},{"refId":791,"refType":"Location","refValue":"Namakwa Sands","enabled":"Y"}]}

Comment: So I have to convert this into CSV and show to the user that he wants to open it download it or cancel it. I am not getting anything how to do it and make compatible to all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from JSON to CSV must be done by hand using JavaScript as the mapping depends on the JSON content.

Once you have built a CSV string you can do something like this:

[Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)

Comment: But does this work for IE9 and above, I am not finding any solution for how to show Download, Open or cancel for it.