# Parse xml to html table or cvs

Tags: html, xml

How can I parse this xml to html table like column error value Error or to CVS, is there some example? thank you

```
<string name="error">Error</string>
```

Comment: What programming language would you be using? xslt? python? lua? c++? Doing this with only html and xml would prove to be more than a simple challenge.

Comment: Thank you for answer, using the simplest language, can I do with jquery?

Comment: of course, jquery has methods like `parseXML()` this would allow you to push xml texts directly into a `var` and then find what you want and push it into a string to create your `csv`. Check this other question that is similar to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery