# Export HTML table to CSV (any browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, export

I have tried a lot of solutions to export HTML data to CSV but none is compatible with all browsers.

This: http://jsbin.com/wewovuciwo/1/edit works great on Firefox, Chrome, but doesn't work on IE. Is it possible to have a function to work on any browser?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '";"',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('table#two'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

Comment: there are numerous libraries or plugins for this that are cross browser tested already, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: One that quickly comes to mind is *table2CSV*.

Comment: Believe me, I tried A LOT and none of then works for Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery

Comment: ^ Doesn't work on IE.