# How to Download a File from the Server Side to the HD

Tags: java, http, download, smartgwt

I generated a pdf file and now its on the server now is there any way to  download it to my desktop for example?

I am using `smartGWT` at the client side and java on my server side .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020949/how-to-download-a-file-using-gwt-client

Comment: This question, as the comment stated, had been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020949/how-to-download-a-file-using-gwt-client)

Answer (score 0):

Write one `Servlet.`Here is the [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-downloading-file-from-the-server-in-servlet) .

Then by using the below code :

```
Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()
        + "/PdfDownload?path=filepath, "", "");
```

assign the filepath by `req.getParametr("filepath");`